# Why is splat operator (*) only used for method parameters?

Tags: python

In python, I can use the splat operator to unpack a list and send the list items as arguments to a function

```
dirs = ['this','is','a','file','path']
path = os.path.join(*dirs)
# path is now 'this/is/a/file/path'
```

My question is, why is this feature limited to method params?

For example, the following is invalid syntax:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [0,*x,4,5]
```

Why doesn't this result in `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`?

Comment: It's a valid syntax in Python 3.5 and newer.

Comment: Wow, they were really quick to implement my suggestion! :)

Comment: Thanks! @vaultah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, it is valid syntax [as of Python 3.5+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations):

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = [0,*x,4,5]
>>> y
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can read about this and more use cases in [PEP 448: "Additional Unpacking Generalizations"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

Comment: Upvote for including the PEP reference.